# Disable echo on esp8266 uart

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Is there a way to disable echo on ESP8266's uart interface?
I use Arduino to program the chip so I can't use AT commands because I uploaded Arduino framework into the chip.
Each time a client tries to connect to the module, it produces some echoes on serial port like this one:

> New client: GET url: /favicon.ico search: : Host: 192.168.1.102:
>   Connection: keep-alive: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87
>   Safari/537.36: Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8: Referer:
>   http://192.168.1.102/admin.html: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch:
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6: : /favicon.ico

Comment: Show some example output. Whats your exact setup? Do you have an Arduino connected to an ESP8266 over serial or do you use the Arduino-Framework to flash the chip directly? What libraries are you using which might be producing the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
Echoes were generated by ESP8266WebServer.h library. I just removed some DEBUG_OUTPUT.print() & DEBUG_OUTPUT.println() statements in Parsing.cpp file and everything is OK now.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Send the command `ATE0` with a newline (`\r\n`).

[image]

Full command reference is available at  https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/ATE .

Comment: I don't think he's using AT commands. He said, he's using Arduino to program the chip.

Comment: I wrote a comment for a clarifacation request.

Answer (score 0):

If that output appears on the serial port of the ESP8266, then it is generated by the sketch you loaded onto the chip from the Arduino IDE.

Thus, if you don't want the output, you'll need to remove the relevant output statements from your sketch.  The output looks similar to what is generated by the WiFiWebServer example sketch, so I'll use that as an example here.  If you use another one, adapt the instructions as suitable for your case.

In the sketch, look for statements like `Serial.println` and `Serial.write`, for example at the beginning of the loop() function you'll find:

```
void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.write(c);
```

Have a look at what each of those lines will write, and remove/comment out the lines for any output you do not wish to see on the serial port.

Comment: thanks for your helpful response but there is no println that would generate such output.

Comment: Are you able to post the code you uploaded to the ESP chip?